# How to open author url linked to a new tab in settings page in the WordPress plugin list

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

When build a plugin a author url link auto created by using plugin structure in settings page in the WordPress plugin list. By default this tab open the same tab. Now how to open this link in a new tab.

More details see the screenshot below.
Thank you.

[image: Image/Screenshot]

Comment: For all plugins, or just for your plugin? It's not really your plugin's business to be changing the behaviour of this link.

Comment: Just for my plugin.